# Android Country code selector lib

Tags: android, country-codes, libphonenumber

Currently I am using https://github.com/hbb20/CountryCodePickerProject
library to allow user to select country, format entered phone number and validate no.

Its good but not fulfilling my requirements. There are couple of issues..

1. If user enter phone no. with country code, its considering as invalid phone no.

i.e India is selected and user enter 91 99 xxx xxxxx.(Invalid).

2. On entering phone no. with country code, flag or country is not getting select.
3. Format is also not applying on changing country.
4. If User edit phone no. which is already saved then on saving its appending country code.

i.e If I am going to change  91 99 xxx xxxxx then its saved as 91  91 99 xxx xxxxx. Which is invalid.

Can anyone suggest me solution or smart library for android.

Answer (score 4):

Try this library, it better than HBB20

Add jitpack.io to your root build.gradle file:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

Add library to your app build.gradle file then sync

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.joielechong:countrycodepicker:2.1.5'
}
```

Add ccp view to xml layout

```
<com.rilixtech.CountryCodePicker
      android:id="@+id/ccp"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Add AppCompatEditText view to layout

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
       android:id="@+id/phone_number_edt"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:hint="phone"
       android:inputType="phone"/>
```

Register the AppCompatEditText with code

```
CountryCodePicker ccp;
AppCompatEditText edtPhoneNumber;

ccp = (CountryCodePicker) findViewById(R.id.ccp);
edtPhoneNumber = (AppCompatEditText) findViewById(R.id.phone_number_edt);

ccp.registerPhoneNumberTextView(edtPhoneNumber);
```

You can check validity of phone number using isValid() method.

Hope this helps. For more info check this link:

https://github.com/joielechong/CountryCodePicker

Comment: does it also validate mobile number length based on country selected?

Comment: Well I think many countries have different length of mobile numbers, some countries I think have mobile number length of 10 or even more than 10...

Comment: yes, that's what I asked, so does that library support such feature? which you mentioned ( i.e CountryCodePicker)

Comment: No, I don't think so...Sorry